# Is there a straightforward way to implement Export and Share feature that still works on Android 12?

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

So, I have been searching the Android developer docs, StackOverflow, Google, Medium and everywhere possible to find a way to implement this feature but everything is just confusing.

**What I want**: In my app, I have an SQLiteOpenHelper database managing my SQLite database and it's very huge. I would like to retrieve some data from the database (different tables) and then zip them and create my own file extension so that I can save it in a folder on the Android device. I found different solutions on the developers' website but the closest I got was going to let the user select where they would want to place the exported file, using a chooser activity, I guess. But I just want to export the file without user interaction (I get to decide where I put the files myself and not the user).

After exporting the file, I would then provide a share button to share the file to another app. Or if the user doesn't want to share it now, then I provide the location of the file so that the user can do it manually, later, if he/she likes.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Save your data in `getExternalFilesDir()`, and use `FileProvider` to make it available via your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` for sharing.

Comment: but according to the docs *When the user uninstalls your app, the files saved in app-specific storage are removed*. And I saw `getExternalFilesDir()` in that guide. Will the data I save get deleted when the user uninstall my app.

Comment: Yes, it will get deleted. However, that is true pretty much of wherever you place the content, if you do not involve the user. Of course, the user is welcome to copy the data out of your `getExternalFilesDir()` location too. One way or another, the user is going to need to get involved.

Comment: Oh, then the user can copy it to another folder and maybe share it later on, and the only problem is the file is deleted when the app is uninstalled. And would that directory be visible to the user ?

Comment: "And would that directory be visible to the user ?" -- yes. Most likely, you have a bunch of similar directories already, on external storage in `Android/`. The location isn't the most user-friendly spot, given that it needs to have unique subdirectories per app and most users are unfamiliar with application IDs.

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply. This is exactly what I needed to know. Now I will make my choice on which route I will take. I also want to add that I read your **First Generation Android Developers book, Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development** and I still visit your blog. Your book really helped me a lot.